# Why is the verb "perceive / یشعرون" negated in two different styles in Baqarah: 9 and 12, and what's the exact difference?

Tags: tafseer, arabic, surat-al-baqarah

The 9th and 12th verses of Baqarah read as follows:

> يُخَادِعُونَ اللَّـهَ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَمَا يَخْدَعُونَ إِلَّا أَنفُسَهُمْ وَمَا يَشْعُرُونَ
>
> They would trick God and believers, and only themselves they deceive
>   and they do not perceive [this].
>
> أَلَا إِنَّهُمْ هُمُ الْمُفْسِدُونَ وَلَـٰكِن لَّا يَشْعُرُونَ
>
> Truly, they are the workers of corruption, but they do not perceive
>   [this].

From a native Arabian's viewpoint, how these two styles of negation (i.e. ما یشعرون and  لا یشعرون) can possibly be different? I know there can be no big semantic difference, yet what about any fine one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is really good and should have been asked in the Arabic Section. As i couldn't find something which reveals the secret behind this choice for those both negation in the few tafsir book i consulted i asked the question in [there](http://arabic.stackexchange.com/questions/271/why-is-the-verb-perceive-%DB%8C%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%86-negated-in-two-different-styles-in-baqarah).

And the Answer was really interesting (shortly): in Arabic both ما and لا are used to negate (a verb) so far so good. But the main difference is that while لا is used to express a negation which is valid in all times (past/present/future), ما only expresses a negation of the time of the verb in your example the verb is conjugated in the present.

Here this would mean at anytime Kufar (non-Believers) my not perceive and this "feeling" is for there actual present situation as we consider the Quran to be valid for all time (i hope i could express myself well!).

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense[, and you were immediately understandable!]